# Codename One - Arabic text in the Simulator

Tags: codenameone

My app contains Arabic text. In Android and iOS devices the text is shown correctly, instead in the Simulator the text is replaced with strange characters. For example, the text "العربية" is shown similar to "[x][x][x][x]" (I cannot reproduce exactly how it is shown).

Platform: Windows 8

In the Netbeans logs generated by Log.p("...") calls, the Arabic text is shown correctly, the problem is only in the Simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the Roboto Android fonts for the desktop that are shipped in the simulator skin. Google only provides some of the locales for those fonts but on the device they work as expected as we use the native builtin Roboto versions.

Comment: Is this problem common with the desktop port and the javascript port of an app?